# second scanf inside function does not work....program does not stop at second scanf?

Tags: c, scanf

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<conio.h>
   void sstring();
    int main()
    {
     char ch1[10],ch2;
     printf("Enter the value of first character : ");
     scanf("%s",&ch1);
     sstring(); 

     getch();
     return 0; 
    } 

    void sstring()
    {    char ch2;
         printf("Enter the value of second character : ");
         scanf("%c",&ch2);   

         printf("Got the second character"); 
    }
```

second scanf inside function does not work....program does not stop at second                                      scanf ?

Comment: Note that although you declared `sstring()`, you did not specify a prototype for it.  In C (but not C++), a declaration of the form `sometype function();` declares the existence of a function which returns `sometype` but the argument list is not specified (but it is not a variable length argument list).  To declare a function prototype for a function that takes no arguments, write `sometype function(void);`.  For consistency, I recommend defining the function with the explicit `(void)` notation too.

Comment: Also, it is a good idea to check the return value from `scanf()`, to make sure it was successful. For example, you might use `if (scanf("%9s", ch1) != 1) ...read failed...`.  Note the absence of an `&` on the array name.  Technically, you're passing the address of an array (of type `char (*)[10]`), rather than the `char *` that `scanf()` expects.  Your compiler should be warning about type mismatches; if it isn't, find out how to make it do so or get a better compiler.  Then heed the warnings!

Comment: can you please suggest for me a good compiler for windows for c and c++ both...please share with me the link from where i could get it...

Comment: Well, I expect MSVC can be persuaded to offer comments like that, but GCC most certainly can.  I've used Cygwin happily on Windows with GCC; there's also MinGW that can be used with GCC.

Answer (score 1):

First, thats not because the second scanf is inside a function.

Thats because the 0xA (return) from the first scanf (you typed enter) is still in the stdin buffer. Note that the %s argument will not read the final "\n" on input. To not affect possible later calls to scanf you should always read both the string and the line delimiter.

```
char string[10], linedelim;
scanf("%s%c", string, &linedelim);
```

Here comes your example again, now working.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void sstring();
int main()
{
 char ch1[10],ch2, linedelim;
 printf("Enter the value of first character : ");
 // read both the string and line delim
 scanf("%s%s",&ch1, &linedelim);
 sstring(); 
 getch();
 return 0; 
} 

void sstring()
{    char ch2;
     printf("Enter the value of second character : ");
     // read the second input
     scanf("%c",&ch2);   
     printf("Got the second character"); 
}
```

Also note, that your example is very fragile as it can easily lead to a buffer overflow when the user inputs more than 10 chars. Imagine the following command line that can easily break your program:

```
$ perl -e 'print "A" x 1000000' | ./a.out
```

A better way than using scanf() for reading a string from input might be using fgets() as you have control over the size of input.

Comment: So after every scanf we need to put fflush?....i mean where to use fflush and where not?

Comment: @kks Forget about the fflush I've mentioned before. fflush() on a input stream will lead to undefined behaviour. Use just another scanf() to eat the newline

Comment: is there any other way to do the same ? i mean if there is some other function so the two scanf statement can be avoided and program runs correctly

Comment: Note that `fflush()` on an input stream has meaning in Windows, but not on Unix.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, I realized this too. I'm not the 'every day use' C expert. But it's always interesting to achieve 'easy' tasks in C! :)